# IE & feature detection with window.open

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

There's a place in my app where I open a new window from javascript:

```
// lookupUrl & name are already defined
window.open(lookupUrl, name, null, false);
```

I don't set options (the third parameter), preferring to fall back on browser defaults, and it works perfectly in Chrome, FF, and Safari.

In Internet Explorer, though, the window that opens can't be resized, has no scrollbars (even when content is bigger than what displays, etc.  So I'd like to do something like this:

```
// lookupUrl & name are already defined
var options = (isIE) ? 'scrollbars=1,resizable=1' : undefined;
window.open(lookupUrl, name, options, false);
```

But I'm having two problems:

1. I'd prefer to use feature detection, rather than browser detection, but I can't figure out what feature I'd be testing for.
2. I've tried several of the [existing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4169160/javascript-ie-detection-why-not-use-simple-conditional-comments) [suggestions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12186325/how-should-i-detect-the-ie-browser) for detecting IE, and they don't seem to work in IE11.

**What else should I be trying?**

Comment: Which versions of IE have you tested in? Which versions of IE do you wish to test for?

Comment: At this point, I want to test for all known versions of IE (in practice, IE 9-11, because our app doesn't support IE <8).

Comment: Why to bother? Other browsers just ignore passed argument if they don't recognize it. Just pass your `options` as it is.